# VBA - split cells with value like =31+44-756+688-7433-899 into multiple cels

Tags: vba, excel

I have cells with formulas like below.

```
=31+44-756+688-7433-899
```

Need a macro or an approach, using which I can separate the numbers into diff cells.

And shuld be like:

```
31, 44, -756, 688, -7433, -899.
```

I can't use split as split can be used for only one delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fool it:

```
Dim strng As String
strng = "31+44-756+688-7433-899"

Dim numbers As Variant
numbers = Split(Replace(strng, "-", "+-"), "+")

Range("A1").Resize(UBound(numbers) + 1). Value = Application.Transpose(numbers)
```

Comment: Nice idea +1 , and this time you got the "tick" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `RegEx`, it's a powerful tool.

Let's say you have `=31+44-756+688-7433-899` in `Range("E2")`, then you can read the text from it using `Formula`.

Afterwards, use the `RegEx` to look for any set of digits up to 16 digits in a row, with `.Pattern = "[0-9]{1,16}"`.

In the code below, I am putting the result one row below Range`("E2")`.

**Code**

```
Sub ExtractNumbers()

Dim Col As Long
Dim Reg1 As Object
Dim RegMatches As Variant
Dim Match As Variant

Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With Reg1
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,16}" ' Match up to 16-digits
End With    

Set RegMatches = Reg1.Execute(Range("E2").Formula)  
If RegMatches.Count >= 1 Then ' <-- at least one match of digits
    Col = 1
    For Each Match In RegMatches            
        Range("E2").Offset(1, Col).Value = Match
        Col = Col + 1
    Next Match
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Both the answers helped me. Thanks guys

Comment: @VadirajKatti you might want to mark one of the answers as "ANSWER"